# how to adjust the limits of this numerical integral?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a complicated function as follows:

```
f[rp_] := (E^(-2 rp^2 \[Gamma]) M^2 norm^2 \[Pi]^(
     3/2) (E^((M \[Alpha] - 2 me rp \[Gamma])^2/(
        2 (M^2 \[Beta] + 
           me^2 \[Gamma]))) ((-1 + E^((4 M me rp \[Alpha] \[Gamma])/(
             M^2 \[Beta] + me^2 \[Gamma]))) M \[Alpha] + 
          2 (1 + E^((4 M me rp \[Alpha] \[Gamma])/(
             M^2 \[Beta] + me^2 \[Gamma]))) me rp \[Gamma]) + 
       E^((M \[Alpha] - 2 me rp \[Gamma])^2/(
        2 (M^2 \[Beta] + me^2 \[Gamma]))) (M \[Alpha] - 
          2 me rp \[Gamma]) Erf[(M \[Alpha] - 2 me rp \[Gamma])/(
         Sqrt[2] M Sqrt[\[Beta] + (me^2 \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
       E^((M \[Alpha] + 2 me rp \[Gamma])^2/(
        2 (M^2 \[Beta] + me^2 \[Gamma]))) (M \[Alpha] + 
          2 me rp \[Gamma]) Erf[(M \[Alpha] + 2 me rp \[Gamma])/(
         Sqrt[2] M Sqrt[\[Beta] + (me^2 \[Gamma])/M^2])]))/(8 Sqrt[2]
      me rp \[Gamma] (M^2 \[Beta] + me^2 \[Gamma]) Sqrt[\[Beta] + (
      me^2 \[Gamma])/M^2]);
```

I want to do some calculations on `f` function to obtain my desire final number. In this vein I need to integrate over `rp` as follows
$$
\int_{|re-r|}^{re+r} f(r_p) dr_p \tag{1}
$$
As Mathematica can't solve (1) analytically, I have to use `NIntegrate`, but when I try (1) numerically

```
NIntegrate[f[rp], {rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}, {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

where the numerical values of constants are

```
me = 1;
mp = 1;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 100;
\[Gamma] = SetPrecision[0.5*M*\[Omega], 50];
{\[Alpha], \[Beta]} = \
{0.407310205953620829699701744175399653613567352294921875`50., 
   24.586618270213069337160050054080784320831298828125`50.};
norm = 189.2253326188998254888908479720045476056553654261503687655661`\
49.454966552225144;
```

I get this error:

```
NIntegrate::nlim: rp = Abs[-1. r+re] is not a valid limit of integration.
```

So how can I solve my integral?! Any idea?

Comment: You doesn't show the call to `NIntegrate`:  Perhaps `re,r` isn't defined yet? You should also provide numerical values for all the parameters!

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: `NIntegrate` is a numerical function and needs numerical parameter values!

Comment: the situation is the same when I add limits of `re` and `r`. Please see the update again

Comment: Does for example `f[1]` give a numerically value?

Comment: Have you defined numerical values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, `M`, `norm`, and `me`?  You haven't provided them in the code above, and `NIntegrate` definitely won't work if you don't.

Comment: Note that if you change the order of integration, by invoking `NIntegrate[f[rp], {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}]`, then you get a different error message about how the integrand is not numeric (because you haven't defined the above parameters numerically.)

Comment: I added the numerical values of the constants. Again I get the error.

Comment: @Michael Seifert yes when I change the order it gives a result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the order of the integration seems to help.  I'm not sure why;  it probably has something to do with how Mathematica does its sampling.  The documentation for `NIntegrate` says that "The first variable given [for the integration region] corresponds to the outermost integral and is done last", so it is plausible that the limits of the first integration variable must be numeric.

```
NIntegrate[f[rp], {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}]
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* 3.98439 *)
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps the order of integration is matter for Mathematica, specially in this case where the limits of third variable is determined by the previous two!